# Forcing Windows Update to Update Metro Apps through Command-Line

Tags: command-line, windows-update, modern-ui, windows-store, windows-rt

I got a couple of Surface RTs and I need a batch file to force Windows RT to update all Store apps; that is, instead of using the Store app's GUI to install updates one by one, I need some kind of command-line utility telling Windows Update to install whatever pending updates there are in the Store for all currently installed Store apps.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can take a look at [the wuauclt utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720477(v=WS.10).aspx), but it's a bit cryptic. Most of the flags aren't even documented, though you can see them with the strings.exe tool from Sysinternals.

Comment: 'wuauclt /UpdateNow' sounds promising

Comment: @weberik I used 'wuauclt /UpdateNow' but there is no response anywhere telling me it's working. I run in and it just...looks at me!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with the command line utility WuInstall - I did not try it with Windows RT, but it indeed worked with other Windows Versions like Windwos XP, 7 and 8

Installing all pending updates goes like

wuinstall /install

Unfortunately, the freeware version is not for download anymore at the product site http://www.wuinstall.com, but there is a time limited trial of the commercial version and some documentation there - and i am pretty sure the free version is still around somewhere online.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WinRT is similar to Win10:

It seems like there is a scheduled task that does this called "Automatic App Update" with the description "Automatically updates the user's Windows store applications."

This could be trigged on the commandline, but I think it would only take effect for the currently logged in user.

There also seems to be a WMI call that can trigger the same. Read more here:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5ac7daa9-54e6-43c0-9746-293dcb8ef2ec/how-to-force-update-of-windows-store-apps-without-launching-the-store-app?forum=win10itprosetup